# ¿Cómo puedo llenar un array dinamicamente y que verifique si un elemento del array ya existe?

Tags: vb.net, array, gridview

Buen día, tengo duda sobre como podría llenar un array en vb.net, especificamente lo necesito dinamico ya que tengo un ComboBox y quiero evitar que el usuario pueda seleccionar un item ya seleccionado, se me ocurrio almacenar los items sleccionados en un array y verificar cada vez que el usuario seleccione otro item si es que ya esta seleccionado.

Cabe mencionar que el ComboBox lo tengo dentro de un GridView.

Comment: Lo que estas pidiendo es labor mas bien para una lista (`List`) o quizas un `HashTable`. De todas maneras no entiendo muy bien que quieres hacer _evitar que el usuario pueda seleccionar un item ya seleccionado_. Quizá si lo explicas mejor podamos ayudarte mas

Comment: Pues en realidad no quiero que sea forzoso el uso del Array podría utilizar una List pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es evitar que el usuario pueda seleccionar el mismo item del combo, por ejemplo supongamos que en mi combo tengo los siguientes items:
Hoja1
Hoja2
Hoja3

El usuario deberá seleccionar una de las opciones,  el combo esta dentro de un GridView, es decir que en mi GridView tengo 5 filas y por cada fila tengo un Combo con los items que mencione, lo que quiero evitar es que si el usuario selecciona una opción ya no pueda seleccionarla en el siguiente combo, en un momento adjunto una imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente.Primero crea un lista de `Integer` donde almacenaras los indices ya seleccionados:

```
Dim listaSeleccionados As New List(Of Integer)()
```

Despues debes controlar el evento `SelectedIndexChanged` o bien al validar la fila, depende de como lo quieras hacer, y añadir el inidice seleccionado a la lista:

```
listaSeleccionados.Add(comboBox.SelectedIndex)
```

Luego cuando vayas a validar los datos, compruebas si el indice ya fue seleccionado con:

```
If listaSeleccionados.Contains(comboBox.SelectedIndex) Then
    MessageBox.Show("No puede seleccionar ese valor")
End If
```

Comment: Ya lo hice, ahora solo tengo un pequeño detalle, cuando valido los datos y comprueba si esta el indice lo hago dentro del evento CellValueChanged de mi grid.

Pero entra 2 veces, no se la razón por la cual entra 2 veces, ¿es mejor ponerlo en otro evento?

Comment: No me parece mal sitio para ponerlo. En principio no debe dispararse dos veces,a no ser que te hayas subscrito dos veces al evento (por ejemplo,una vez en el designer y otra en tu codigo) Compruebalo, puedes por ejemplo comentar la subscripcion en tu codigo y probar,si se dispara una vez probablemente este ya en el designer

Comment: Ya lo tengo, había un error de mi parte en el evento. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!.